# Pyttsx not saying all text when using non default voice

Tags: python, text-to-speech

I created a small module to speak the text that is sent to it.
It works fine if I don't use engine.setProperty to set the voice, but if I set the voice it will only play the first command.

```
import pyttsx

def speak( text ):
    if text != "":
        engine = pyttsx.init()
        engine.setProperty('voice', "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens\VW Kate") #if I don't do this line then it says both the commands
        engine.say( text )
        engine.runAndWait()

    else:
        print "you didnt enter anything"

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        speak("Hello")
        speak("This one won't play unless I use the default voice")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should try the following code snippet :

```
import pyttsx
engine = pyttsx.init()
engine.say('Sally sells seashells by the seashore.')
engine.say('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.')
engine.runAndWait()
```

which is originally from [this page](http://packages.python.org/pyttsx/engine.html)